# MarkLogic 6.0: Query to get text from child element

Tags: spring-mvc, xquery, marklogic

I need to fetch text in `<title>`. The XQuery I tried is below.

**XML**

```
<jrnl:prelim>
  <heading searchtype="TITLE">
     <title>Les apports de la loi au secteur des transports (articles 1 à 30)</title>
     <subtitle>. - L. n° 2015-990, 6 août 2015, Titre Ier : Libérer l'activité - Chapitre Ier : Mobilité : JO 7 août 2015, p. 13537</subtitle>
  </heading>
```

**XQuery**

```
 declare namespace jrnl = "http://www.lexis-nexis.com/glp/jrnl";
let $x := doc("/FR/PRESSE_ACTUALITE/PRESSE/PS_KPRE-437971_MAR04.xml")
let $qy := cts:element-query(xs:QName("jrnl:prelim"),cts:and-query(( 
   cts:element-attribute-word-query(
                          xs:QName("heading"),
                          xs:QName("searchtype"), 
                          "TITLE"
                        ), cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("title"), "Action des douanes dans la lutte contre la ") )))
return cts:contains($x, $qy)
```

Comment: You changed the question after I answered it, so I'm deleting my answer. Please be mindful that when you do this it wastes the time of people who are trying to help you.

Comment: what did i change?  i just updated the xquery

Comment: @wst tell me how to fetch text data inside <title> by accessing <heading searchtype="TITLE">

Answer (score 2):

If you have already retrieved the document, you can just use an XPath:

```
$x/jrnl:prelim/heading[@searchtype eq "TITLE"]/title[contains(string(.), "...")]
```

It is more common to pass a cts:query to a cts:search() to retrieve documents instead of using cts:query to inspect documents after retrieval.

By the way, MarkLogic 6.0 is quite old and lacks many important features in MarkLogic 8 (for instance, native JSON support).  You should upgrade if at all possible.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: actually the content in $x is not available in real time. that is the problem. otherwise i would follow this approach

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "not available in real time."  Are you saying the code above is not the actual code you're executing?